Why do tan and the inverse trig functions look like this on the unit circle?
I'm learning trigonometry, and I'm confused about the representations of trig functions on the unit circle:

I understand why sin and cos are placed like that (sin(x) = O/H = O/1 = O, etc.) but I'm having trouble grasping the others. E.g. Why is tan exactly equal to that tangent line? What about sec, csc, cot? How did people figure it all out?

It is all about similar triangles. As long as you have two similar triangles where you know two sides on one triangle and one of the corresponding sides on the other triangle, you can determine the other corresponding side on the second triangle.
To start, use similar triangles to see why the triangle side length marked as "tan" must equal $\tan \theta$.
Some function names in your diagram, like versin and cvs, are obsolete. They remind me of the Onion article here.
Note: there are no inverse trig functions in the diagram. The reciprocal of a trig function could be called a reciprocal, but don't call it an "inverse trig function" since that means something else.

Thanks for the link !
